# Intermittent 520 error in webpage

Tags: error

For the last two days a website of one of my clients has been suddenly giving a 520 error when visited.
Refreshing the page seems to fix it for the moment, after a while of clicking links it happens again.

I'm using Cloudflare.
I've tried deleting cache both locally and from cloudflare.
I've tried checking redirection - it's all okay and nothing was changed regardless.
I've tried checking from many computers / cellphones, error is same.
Webpage is hosted with godaddy, uses wordpress. No updates happened lately.

Cloudflare's advice is to check the webpage with curl, it gives no useful info.

Any advice?

Comment: Disable CloudFlare's proxy (click the cloud over your `A` record under DNS so that it turns grey) and see if it reoccurs - that will tell you if it's specific to your server. You should also check your server's error log to view the errors there. If there are none listed, then you likely have either a problem with your hardware (e.g., drive failure, exceeded resources, etc...) or connection to the Internet

Answer (score 1):

This might happen due to various reasons explained here by CloudFlare: https://support.cloudflare.com/hc/en-us/articles/200171936-Error-520-Web-server-is-returning-an-unknown-error